# No value accessor for form control name: 'canvas-zoom' after upgrading to Angular 15

Tags: angular, angular-material

I just upgraded Angular & Angular Material to v15. I started to get various errors and I narrowed them down to one component that is using [`mat-slider`](https://rc.material.angular.io/components/slider/overview).

The code was-

```html
<mat-slider [min]="minZoom" [max]="maxZoom" step="0.1" [(ngModel)]="zoomValue" class="w-20"
            [disabled]="selectedFeature === EngagementFeature.PUSH"
            (input)="zoomChanged($event)"></mat-slider>
```

After I ran the migration-

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

The code got changed to-

```html
<mat-slider [min]="minZoom" [max]="maxZoom" step="0.1" [(ngModel)]="zoomValue" class="w-20"
            [disabled]="selectedFeature === EngagementFeature.PUSH" #ngSlider>
    <input matSliderThumb
           (input)="zoomChanged({source: ngSliderThumb, parent: ngSlider, value: ngSliderThumb.value})"
           #ngSliderThumb="matSliderThumb"/>
</mat-slider>
```

Which I further cleaned up to-

```html
<mat-slider [min]="minZoom" [max]="maxZoom" step="0.1" [(ngModel)]="zoomValue" class="w-20"
            [disabled]="selectedFeature === EngagementFeature.PUSH" name="canvas-zoom">
    <input matSliderThumb (dragEnd)="zoomChanged($event)"/>
</mat-slider>
```

And I started getting this error-

```
ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'canvas-zoom'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01203
    at _throwMissingValueAccessorError (forms.mjs:3165:11)
    at setUpControl (forms.mjs:2938:13)
    at NgModel._setUpStandalone (forms.mjs:4025:9)
    at NgModel._setUpControl (forms.mjs:4013:37)
    at NgModel.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:3972:18)
    at NgModel.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:1574:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2498:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2457:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2408:9)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:9153:17)
```

I tried to dig into the stacktrace but nothing helped. I also tried to set the `name` attribute without success. Followed the [migration doc](https://rc.material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#slider) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon comparing the v14 documentation https://v14.material.angular.io/components/slider/api#MatSlider, I realised that `@Input() value` & `@Output() input` properties are no longer available in `mat-slider` in v15.

Since they introduced `MatSliderThumb`, which now have `@Input() value` & `@Output() valueChanges` property, so the fix was to move `[(ngModel)]` (or `formControl`) to `matSliderThumb`-

```html
<mat-slider [min]="minZoom" [max]="maxZoom" step="0.1" class="w-20"
            [disabled]="selectedFeature === EngagementFeature.PUSH">
    <input matSliderThumb (dragEnd)="zoomChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="zoomValue"/>
</mat-slider>
```